# how to get json/array from ajax responseText in to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using codeigniter in my project.When I am trying to get array element from encoded array, something id going wrong.How can I get encoded json array in my javaScript?

### index.html

```html
    
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function sendMessage(){
        var message=document.getElementById('chatInput').value;
        var receverID=document.getElementById('id').value;
        if(message==''){
            alert("please enter message");
        }

        new Ajax.Request('index.php', {
            method:'get',
            evalJSON: true,
            parameters: {
                message: message,
                id: receverID
            },

            onSuccess: function(transport){

                var data= transport.responseText;
                console.log(data);

            },
            onError: function() {
                alert('Error');
            },
            onComplete: function() {
            }
        });
    }
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea name="chatInput" id="chatInput" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea><br />
     <input type="button" name="send_message"  onclick="sendMessage()" Value="Send"/>
     <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="5">
    </body>
    </html>
```

### index.php

```html
<?php
     header('Content-type: application/json');
     $data['message'] = $_GET['message'];
     $data['sender_id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
     $data['user_id'] = $_GET['id'];
     $this->model_users->setMessage($data);
     echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(transport.responseText);` ?

Comment: {"message":"hello world","sender_id":"1","user_id":"3"}<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   ........
    </head>
<body >
..... some code ......
</body>
</html>

Comment: I want to get for example, the first element of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems that you have a HTML in your response. It's a good practice to put `exit` after `json_encode` call when you expect JSON response.

Try to put this in your `index.php` and it should works:

```
echo json_encode($data);
exit; // terminate the current script
```

Comment: Can you say, How can I get the first element in array?

Comment: First, please mark answer as accepted, please. And, what you mean by first element? Let me know which element from your response you want to access?

Comment: the result of console.log(transport.responseText); is following: {"message":"hello world","sender_id":"1","user_id":"3"}

Comment: Now I want to get "message"

Comment: Try: `console.log(data.message);`